# Права юзера над другим юзером в django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как сделать чтоб тип юзеров или группа ( допустим учитель) мог изменять информацию про студента ( стандартного юзера) но только одно поле (avg_mark).
И как сделать для этого форму на сайте?
пример класса студента

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    personname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    avr_mark = models.FloatField(default = 0.00)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Через django админку можно каждому пользователю, группе назначать права на модели, но не на поля. Поэтому, если вам нужно дать доступ на изменение одного поля, то сделайте дополнительную модель AverageMark, свяжите ее полем один_к_одному и дайте доступ на запись преподавателю на эту модель:

```
class AverageMark(models.Model):
    avr_mark = models.FloatField(default = 0.00)

class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    personname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    avr_mark = models.OneToOneField(
        AverageMark,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Если задача не стоит редактировать студента в админке, то можно оставить вашу модель как вы сделали и для формы выводить только поле fields = ['avr_mark'], смотрите пример ниже.

2) Редактирование формы можно сделать - через [админку](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls), через [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/), через [создание простой формы](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).
- если нет требований создавать отдельную форму, то можете дать доступ в админке к нужным моделям и редактировать там. На странице с информацией о студентах делаете ссылки как написано в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls):

```
{% load admin_urls %}
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'add' %}">Добавить студента</a>
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' student.pk %}">Удалить</a>
```

где opts - это название приложения и модели (например appname_student)

Я раньше делал так:

```
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Перейти в администрирование сайта</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:appname_student_add' %}">Добавить студента</a>
<a href="{% url 'admin:appname_student_change' choice.id %}">Редактировать</a>
```

Ну а если нужно делать форму отдельно от админки, то в views.py пишите:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from appname.models import Student

class StudentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Student
    fields = ['avr_mark']
    template_name = 'student_create.html'

class StudentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Student
    fields = ['avr_mark']

class StudentDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Student
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('student-list')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from myapp.views import StudentCreate, StudentUpdate, StudentDelete

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('student/add/', StudentCreate.as_view(), name='student-add'),
    path('student/<int:pk>/', StudentUpdate.as_view(), name='student-update'),
    path('student/<int:pk>/delete/', StudentDelete.as_view(), student='author-delete'),
]
```

в темплейте student_create.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

То что я написал - пример. Писал по памяти, могут быть ошибки.

Comment: StudentCreate немного не правильно, там пароль хэшировать надо

Answer (score 0):

Просто отображаете всем, кто не входит в группу Teachers, поле avg_mark как поле только для чтения.

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['personname', 'avg_mark', 'avatar']

    def viewed_by_teacher(self, request):
        return (request.user
                       .groups
                       .filter(name='Teachers')
                       .exists())

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = super(StudentAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        if not self.viewed_by_teacher(request):
            fields.remove('avg_mark')
        return fields

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, object):
        if not self.viewed_by_teacher(request):
            return ['avg_mark']
```